# How to autosize view without auto layout in iOS

Tags: ios5, ios6, interface-builder, autolayout, autosize

I have a problem that I can't understand **resizing** views. My deployment target is *iOS 5.0*, so I have disabled `auto layout` in the interface builder to make it compatible with *iOS 5.0*. The view does not resize automatically. Following is an example:

**Interface Builder Snapshot:**

[image]

**4-inch screen:**

[image]

**3.5-inch screen *(has problem)*:**

[image]

As you can see, the button at the bottom of the view goes out of the screen. The background image also does not resize automatically. I can not understand how I can solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the pre-autolayout world! You must set the autoresizing "springs and struts" so that the stuff at the bottom is attached to the bottom of the superview and *not* the top. So, struts to the bottom, springs to the top. That way, as the superview gets larger and smaller, the stuff at the bottom moves with the bottom.

You *could* alternatively reposition the stuff in code, but there's no need in this situation.

Here's the section on autoresizing from my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autoresizing

The part about the superview and the background image not being resized is a different matter. Is this the view of a UIViewController? If so, then if you are putting the UIViewController into the view controller parent-child hierarchy correctly, it *will* be resized by its parent. But you have not shown any code, so there's no telling what this view may be or how it is supposed to get into the interface.